# How to use Google API client library?

Tags: android, google-places-api

I want to use Google places API in android application.

which Jar library do i need to add?

i have already downloaded the zip contains all the jars with their source.jar

i doc't know which jar should i use in android 2.2 and what to do with source.jars

Answer (score 2):

Please follow this tutorial: http://blog.brianbuikema.com/2010/08/android-development-part-1-using-googles-places-api-to-develop-compelling-location-based-mobile-applications/ and you can move ahead quickly in you answers.

It seems to me that you do not need to include any jar file; but when creating new new project in android please select Google API as your project platform.

Comment: Thanks Jigar, I am trying to follow this tutorial http://ddewaele.blogspot.in/2011/05/introducing-google-places-api.html, i have implemented  this, it requires some jar file

Comment: You shouldn't need any Jar file. The places API is basically just a async fetch to return xml/json.